# What did the Engineers actually initiate on Earth in Prometheus?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

In the beginning of *Prometheus* (the opening scene and the briefing scene), the film conveys that the Engineers did something on Earth that either started life itself on Earth, or started human life on Earth. Does the movie make clear which of the two alternatives it actually tries to convey?

The only thing I found to be somewhat related to that question is the biologist in the briefing stating (I'm paraphrasing here) that he isn't ready to throw out 300 years of Darwinism for some cave drawings. Of course, that comment doesn't make much sense in either scenario (theory of evolution doesn't concern itself with abiogenesis at all, and a single species being added externally to an already existing ecosystem doesn't contradict the theory either), so it doesn't help to decide in either way.

Comment: Do you have new evidence indicating that it *IS* Earth in the opening scene? I've seen a lot of discussion debating whether or not it's Earth, LV-223, LV-426 or any one of the other planets that the "Engineers" have experimented on.

Comment: No, I have no evidence for that. However, the scientists seem convinced that the engineers did at least something similar to the opening scene on earth. Of course, they could be wrong, as there is nothing in the ancient depictions actually pointing to the engineers actually creating anything; they could just have been visitors.

Comment: They initiated the eventual writing of the Lost series finale.

Comment: @JohnO: that's for sure. What's unclear is whether this was better or worse than sending xenomorph-bomb-equipped battleships in our general direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Prometheus* Blu-Ray's Extras menu reveals what the Engineers were doing: seeding Earth with *intelligent* life:

> **Scene 7: Arrival of the Engineers**
>
> The Engineers touch down on prehistoric Earth for a sacred ritual devoted to the seeding of Intelligent life. Whereas the Theatrical version of the scene is devoted to the Lone Sacrifice Engineer, this early cut features several of his comrades, including the Elder Engineer. The ceremony was filmed with dialogue but unsatisfied with the result, Ridley Scott removed the dialogue entirely.

[image: Screen Capture of the above text]

As it was mentioned, there was already plant life on the planet. This can been seen from the areal shots.

Answer (score 7):

It's not so much a representation of what happened *on Earth* rather than what the Engineers *do*: seed life through self-sacrifice.

There are a lot of religious undertones as well. The Engineer hesitates before drinking the cup, something akin to Matt 26:39:

> And he went a little further, and fell on his face, and prayed, saying, O my Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me: nevertheless not as I will, but as thou wilt.

There are many other allusions to religion, particularly Christianism (and obviously Ancient Greek mythology). [This paper](https://cavalorn.livejournal.com/584135.html) is quite detailed about it.

One thing is for certain: there was plant life on that planet, as can be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKR5tc33n5s) at 1:48 and in more detail in [this picture](https://web.archive.org/web/20121024205857/https://geektyrant.com/storage/2011-post-images/prometheus-bts-engineerhd.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1339715709780). Thus, the Engineers are bringing in foreign DNA to swerve life on the planet with their design.

Comment: Is plant life shown in the opening sequence? I honestly can't remember.

Comment: Why do you believe that they're seeding life at all? There has also been speculation that he was initiating the destruction of life on the planet by infecting himself with the black liquid.

Comment: @phantom42 2 things. First, the DNA broke down then rejoined in the animation at the beginning. Second, in the case of the humans infected by the liquid, life was born, first as Elizabeth's baby, and remade as the chest-burster that came out of the Engineer. The Engineers schtick is that they create life through destruction (David says something similar at some point).

Comment: Yes, but their plan is to destroy life on Earth. I don't know I'd agree that counts as "seeding life" if they're only creating a new lifeform for the express purpose of wiping out all existing life on whichever planet the first scene takes place on.

Comment: @phantom42 I suppose it's a point of view. The idea that's presented in the paper is that of a cycle, that the Engineers create life through destruction, again and again.

Comment: @phantom42 But if the first planet is Earth then they are either seeding life for the first time, or wiping out some other pre-human species and implanting humans.

Comment: @MPelletier, this is a nice answer, especially with that link. However, I didn't notice any plants in the opening sequence (which might very well be because I didn't know the presence or absence of plants would have any relevancy to me later on and hence didn't look for them). Maybe you could add a description of where exactly plants are shown (I'd guess it must have been either in the flyover in the very beginning or in the water when the engineer is dissolving).

Comment: @WolfgangGroiss You know, I'm starting to doubt it myself. I'm editing my question. I remain by my stance that it's not a representation of what happened on Earth specifically.

Comment: <strike>Okay. You were right about the plants: They can [clearly be seen](http://geektyrant.com/storage/2011-post-images/prometheus-bts-engineerhd.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1339715709780)</strike> - Oh gosh, i totally didn't notice the visible camera equipment there. That is obviously NOT a screenshot from the actual movie, in which the green stuff might as well have been edited out. To whoever is reviewing my last edit to this answer, my edit is wrong.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I've found something. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKR5tc33n5s) at 1:48 plants are clearly visible (on the same rock that can be seen on the screenshot from my previous comment) and those appear to be screenshots from the actual movie. (also at 1:00 there seem to be trees in the background)